# Speed up loading external javascript file via a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, unix, external, bookmarklet, performance

I have a bookmarklet that (functionally) works perfectly.  You click the bookmarklet and a popup appears.  This popup is generated by a combination of javascipt files located on my Virtual Private Server.

Code Example:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://mydomain.com/myjavascript.js';})();">My Bookmarklet</a>
```

When I use the bookmarklet on my website the popup loads in 1-2 seconds.  However, if I use the bookmarklet on a different site it takes at least 5 seconds - sometimes more.  Obviously I'm trying to find a way to get the 5 second load time closer to the 1-2 second load time, because most of my testers keep thinking the bookmarklet is broken since it takes so long for the popup to appear.

My theory is that my server (which is a unix server that uses Plesk and Virtuosso), is restricting how quickly it allows its files to be loaded to an external site.  However, thus far I haven't been able to find anything in my server's managment software that suggests that for certain.  If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this I'd be highly appreciative.

Comment: Have you tried to get the file with wget or something like that? Also, could it be that the DNS lookup is slow?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that your theory - that the problem is originating in your server - is correct.

It seems more likely to me that problem is probably because you are testing on two different pages.

I would try to verify that the apparent speed problem is actually one of loading, and not actually one of execution. Does it seem like it is slower because you are checking network activity, or just because it completes its work slower. I have been surprised in the past by how much slower a piece of JS code ran on one page vs. another. I too thought the file was loading slow, but that wasn't actually the case.

Comment: Thanks for you response.  I've actually tested the bookmarklet on literally dozens of sites.  It's consistently in the 5 seconds or more category for every site I've tested (e.g. Amazon, Yahoo, etc.).  I've tested it on multiple pages on my site and consistently gotten 1-2 seconds.  I've actually already attempted to address this as an execution issue by minimizing my javascript as much as possible to get the file size as small as possible.  Doing so has not noticeably decreased the load time, so again I come back to a server issue.

Comment: Nothing in your reply convinces me it isn't an execution problem. On your site it is fast and on every other site it is slow. You are still comparing apples and oranges. You say you "attempted to address this as an execution issue by minimizing my javascript... to get the file size as small as possible", but file size and execution speed are not equivalent. You should be checking the network activity using the web console in FF or Chrome.